# regular expression for fraction number "4 3/4"?

Tags: php, regex

I want to create regular expression for fraction number like `4 3/4` or you can say mixed fraction.

There is a field in my project, whenever i search decimal or any other number so it gives perfect result but if user give this type of number `4 3/4` it returns results where `4<"space">`

Example:-In PHP

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/',$value1))
{

}
```

Comment: Like this, or is the fractional portion meant to be optional? `^\d+\s\d+\/\d+$`

Comment: Why does your pattern start with `[0-9]` rather than just `\d`?

Comment: @MrLister because of integer  that i will search with this expression